# Spring 3 MVC integration with DWR with Annotation

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, dwr

Can anybody please help me finding any good tutorial/sample code about integrating **Spring3-MVC** and **DWR** .I have searched hours on internet but can't find anything useful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the following tutorials/articles:

1. [Spring MVC 3 and DWR 3 Integration Tutorial](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-mvc-3-and-dwr-3-integration.html)
2. [Integrating DWR 3 with Spring 3 @MVC](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?98529-Integrating-DWR-3-with-Spring-3-MVC)
3. [DWR and Spring](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/integration/spring.html)
4. [Spring Tutorial - AJAX enabling Spring Services using DWR](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olT4HMeru58) (Video Tutorial)
5. [Spring and DWR 2.0 (Ajax) working example](http://manmalikmachine.wordpress.com/2007/11/27/spring-and-dwr-20-ajax-working-example/)

Comment: @kohran i already have looked at them but all of them are missing something .i would be grateful if you could provide me some sample working code.

Comment: @DanglingPiyush the first one includes source code as well but I added two more tutorials (4 and 5) that I've found with code implementation. Hopefully you will find what you seeking for.