# DWR 3 integration in Spring 3 environment without XML

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, dwr, spring-java-config

I started a new Spring project without any XML configuration file. I become a big fan of annotation config. So I tried to include DWR library, which I used in my last projects. But I cannot find any tutorial, how to integrate DWR 3 in an java config spring environment.

Is this already possible, or can somebody recommend another solution where I dont have to use XML configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below two links.

Sample codes are also in the link

http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-mvc-3-and-dwr-3-integration.html

[Spring 3 MVC integration with DWR with Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985742/spring-3-mvc-integration-with-dwr-with-annotation)

Comment: Thx, I have already seen those links and they all use XML configuration.